# Use command line to browse LinearModel object properties

Tags: matlab

I'm following the regression tutorial at http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/estimate-regression-model-with-multiplicative-arima-errors.html.  In particular, I am browsing the object Fit=fitlm(X,logY).  I know I can double-click the object in the Workspace window, but I often don't want more windows.  I might just want to list the members at the command line.  According to http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ug/linear-model-structures.html#bq4gq_u-20, I should be able to do this with the get method.  However, Matlab informs me that the Linear Model class doesn't have a get method [tried Fit.get, Fit.get(), and get(Fit)].  What am I missing?

As for browsing the properites using the GUI window, I'm finding that the Residuals property is not present.  According to http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel-class.html, it should be present.  Thanks for any light that can be shed on my misunderstanding of the class.

I've posted this at:
http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/b0jHdrX6_ZY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all the property names of an object using the [`properties`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/properties.html) function. In your case:

```
properties(Fit)
```

Comment: I think I see my confusion.  The get function is class specific.  And 
so one can't just blindly select a link that is returned from a search 
in the doc window.  One has to pay careful attention to the specific 
class to which it applies.  Tahnks, Dan.